# Flutter borders

Tags: flutter, border

Hello I very new to Flutter and I am trying to create a button, but I have a problem with this.

This is the code:

```
Align(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.03, 0.13),
  child: FFButtonWidget(
    onPressed: () {
      print('Login pressed ...');
    },
    text: 'Login',
    options: FFButtonOptions(
      width: 130,
      height: 40,
      color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
      textStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).subtitle2.override(
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        width: 1,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
  ),
),
```

This is the error:

> The argument type 'BorderRadius' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double?'.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using FlutterFlow.
Here you don't need to give the border radius like this

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
```

Do it like this

```
borderRadius: 8
```

This is because FlutterFlow button widget is not like the usual Flutter button widget. They are modified versions of actual Flutter widgets.

In your case, properties of FFButtonWidget is set using this class

```
FFButtonOptions()
```

This class probably takes borderRadius as a double value and internally sets it like this

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
```

So you have to give the required borderRadius as a double value.

Comment: Thank you so much @rrtrr let's see if it is going to work

Answer (score 0):

The `borderRadius` field in the FFButtonOptions require a double parameter. Try

```
borderRadius: 8.0
```

It is hard to say, because I do not know how the `FFButtonWidget` looks like. Normally, your way of setting the border radius would be good for material widgets, for instance:

```
Align(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.03, 0.13),
  child: Container(
    width: 130,
    height: 40,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print('Login pressed ...');
      },
      child: Text('Login'),
      style: ButtonStyle(
        textStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).subtitle2.override(
          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Probably the `FFButtonWidget` takes a double parameter and finally transforms it into

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
```

But if you want to use material widgets, you can check how the buttons work in Flutter [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons).

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that before I asked on stack @Patryk Bozek